# Swift generic number types and math

Tags: swift, generics, math

I'm trying to wrap my head around the ins and outs of Swift generics and make some common math functions. I'm trying to implement a `mod` function, but not quite sure the best way to get it working using generics.

Here's what my `mod` function looks like:

```
func mod<N: NumericType, I: IntegerType>(_ x: N, _ y: I) -> N {
    return x - y * floor(x/y)
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
error: binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'N' and 'I'
    return x - y * floor(x/y)
```

And here's my `NumericType` declaration for decimal and integer type numbers:

```
protocol NumericType: Comparable {
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func %(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

protocol DecimalType: NumericType {
    init(_ v: Double)
}

protocol IntegerType: NumericType {
    init(_ v: Int)
}

extension CGFloat : DecimalType { }
extension Double  : DecimalType { }
extension Float   : DecimalType { }

extension Int     : IntegerType { }
extension Int8    : IntegerType { }
extension Int16   : IntegerType { }
extension Int32   : IntegerType { }
extension Int64   : IntegerType { }
extension UInt    : IntegerType { }
extension UInt8   : IntegerType { }
extension UInt16  : IntegerType { }
extension UInt32  : IntegerType { }
extension UInt64  : IntegerType { }
```

Comment: Note that as of Swift 3, all integer types conform to `Integer`, and all floating point types conform to `FloatingPoint`. Both protocols already define the basic arithmetic operators like +,i,*,/. Perhaps that helps to simplify the code a bit.

Comment: @MartinR This did the trick! Greatly simplified my code, no more custom protocols https://twitter.com/iamkgn/status/773778299487002624 Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Swift 3, all floating point types conform to `FloatingPoint`,
and all integer types conform to `Integer`.
Both protocols define the basic arithmetic operations like +,-,*,/. 
Also the `floor()` function is defined for `FloatingPoint`
arguments.

Therefore in your case I would define *two* implementations, one for
integers and one for floating point values:

```
func mod<N: Integer>(_ x: N, _ y: N) -> N {
    return x - y * (x/y) // or just: return x % y
}

func mod<N: FloatingPoint>(_ x: N, _ y: N) -> N {
    return x - y * floor(x/y)
}
```

`FloatingPoint` has also a `truncatingRemainder` method,
`a.truncatingRemainder(b)` is the "floating point equivalent"
to `a % b` for integers. It gives the 
gives the same result as your `mod` function if both
operands have the same sign.

Answer (score 2):

```
static func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
```

This means both `lhs` and `rhs` has to be of the **same type**.

In `x / y`, `x` is of the type `N`, and `y` is of type `I`. So `x` and `y` have **different types** and therefore `x / y` does not work.

You need to cast `y` from `I` to `N` first:

```
let numericY = N(integer: y)
return x - numericY * floor(x / numericY)
```

which means your NumericType need to be able to initialize from an IntegerType, besides having `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`.

```
protocol NumericType: Comparable {
    init<I: IntegerType>(integer: I)
    ...
}
```

(Also, `floor<N: NumericType>(n: N) -> N` should exist to make the whole expression compile.)

Comment: Awesome, this is really helpful but when I add the `init` to the `NumericType` protocol then all the extensions need to conform, is there a way around this? `error: type 'CGFloat' does not conform to protocol 'NumericType'`

Comment: @keegan3d Unfortunately you need to implement that method yourself. You could try `self.init(integer.toIntMax())`.